# How to add day of week name from daterange period

Tags: php, laravel, date, date-range, php-carbon

I'm using Laravel and Carbon.

I create a function to add 'availability' like:

```
public function createAvailability(Request $request) {
    $availability = new Availability($request->all());
    $availability->save();

    return Redirect::back();
}
```

I send 'start' and 'end' data to request, so example data is: `$request->start = '01/07/2018'; $request->end= '22/07/2018';`

and now I insert in database data like:

[image]

What I want to do is to insert data in a database like:

[image]

so for the first 7 days, I want to insert names with the same 'start' and 'end' data... or if start date is 01/07 and end date is 03/07 I want to insert just 3 days with day of week names...

How I can do that?

Also here is my Availablity class with protected dates:

```
class Availability extends Model
{

    protected $dates = [ 'start','end' ];

    public function setStartAttribute($date) {
        $this->attributes['start']= Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date);
    }

    public function getStartAttribute($date){
        return (new Carbon($date))->format('d-m-Y');
    }

    public function setEndAttribute($date) {
        $this->attributes['end']= Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date);
    }

    public function getEndAttribute($date){
        return (new Carbon($date))->format('d-m-Y');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want this in the DB? You could easily get the day of week from Carbon when you retrieve the record and probably have less writing to do for it.

Comment: Yes, there is a reason for that ... I need it in database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be what you are wanting

```
function days($start, $end){
  $current = strtotime($start);
  $end = strtotime($end);
  while($current <= $end && $current <= ($current * 7))){ // go until the last day or seven days, whichever comes first
    $day = date("l", $current);
    $availability = new Availability();
    $availability->start_date = date('d/m/Y', $current);
    $availability->end_date = date('d/m/Y', $end);
    $availability->day_of_week = date("l", $current);
    $availability->save();
    $current = $current + 86400;
}
days($request->input('start'), $request->input('end'));
```

Comment: can you please update my function from above /createAvailability ?

Comment: SOrry this is not what I expect... I know how to add day name at table - what I need to do is to add 7x in database but if there is time difference 3 days then to add just 3 days starting with first date day name

Comment: Sorry but your question is still not clear. In your picture above you have an entry for each day of the week with beginning and end dates that don't match the day of the week for 6 of the entries. Do you mean that for each day in the time span of beginning to end date you want a separate entry? It sounds like you need to do some parsing to get how long of a time span it is and then generate the days based on that. I don't think anyone here should be charged with writing a method that does all of that for you. I hint would be to convert dates using strtotime() to do your calculations.

Comment: yes, for each date between dates but max 7 need to add entry with day name

Comment: I write this function: $i = 0;
for($date = $start; $date->lte($end); $date->addDay()) {
        $dates[] = $date->format('l');
        $i++;
        if ($i == 7) {
            break;
        }
    }